# Service pricing on magento

Tags: custom-options, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, advanced-pricing

We are considering using magento to create our ecommerce solution for selling mobile repair services. Here, in a typical scenario, a repair job is created by the customer and damaged mobile is sent to the service center by courier. The technician estimates the labor and provides a quote for that job to the customer manually. Customer reviews the charge and makes a payment. Can this pricing be achieved in Magento?
Thanks,
Noorul

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is requirement not related to coding at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple **NO**,

this could be not possible by default magento.

It requires customization.

by doing customization you can achieve what you say.